# use values of first array to select values of second array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to use the values of my first array $selection (which are always numbers) as the keys for the other array $categories and output only the selected keys.

See code below, very new to php.

```
<?php

    $selection = array('1', '4', '5');
    $categories = array('fruit', 'bread', 'desert', 'soup', 'pizza');

    $multiple = array_combine($selection, $categories);

    print_r($multiple);

?>
```

so it should output something like:

```
Array ( [1] => fruit [4] => soup [5] => pizza )
```

Comment: How do you want to handle cases where the length of $selection and $categories differ?

Comment: exactly. This example here only works when the number of values are the same. I need a solution to just select the values of the second array with the given values of the first.

Comment: So where are we with this question?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

Just get the [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) from both arrays: `$selection` and `$categories`.

Note that since an array is index based 0 you have to go through your `$selection` array with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and subtract one from each value to then use [`array_flip()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php).

And at the end you can simply [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) the intersect of both arrays with the `$selection` array.

```
$result = array_combine($selection,
    array_intersect_key(
        $categories,
        array_flip(
            array_map(function($v){
                return $v-1;
            }, $selection)
        )
    ));
```

output:

```
Array ( [1] => fruit [4] => soup [5] => pizza )
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this works for you?

```
<?php
    $selection = array('1', '4', '5');
    $categories = array('fruit', 'bread', 'desert', 'soup', 'pizza');
    $multiple = array();

    foreach($selection as $value) {
        if (isset($categories[$value - 1])) 
            $multiple[$value] = $categories[$value - 1];
        }
    }

    print_r($multiple);
?>
```

Comment: How does this in any way solve his problem? `isset($categories[$value]` will always be false.

Comment: I don't think so, why would it be?

Comment: yes it does, much simpler this way cause it doesn't matter for me where the counting starts. Thanks Federico and Rizier123!